# The property '' on entity type could not be found since upgrading to EF 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've upgraded my app to Ef Core 2.1 and a query that used to work in EF 2.0 is now giving errors.

I use variations of the same query across multiple different tables and they are all failing with the same error now that I've upgraded

Here are my models:

```
public class Promotion  
{
    public int PromotionId { get; set; }   
    // I've removed the other fields  

    public virtual ICollection<PromotionTopicJoin> PromotionTopicJoins {get; set;}

}

public class PromotionTopic  
{
    public int PromotionTopicId { get; set; }     

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PromotionTopicJoin> PromotionTopicJoins {get; set;}


}

public class PromotionTopicJoin
{
    public int PromotionId { get; set; }
    public Promotion Promotion { get; set; }
    public int PromotionTopicId { get; set; }
    public PromotionTopic PromotionTopic { get; set; }

}
```

And this is the query that I run:

```
    return await _context.PromotionTopics
        .Where(p => p.PromotionTopicId == TopicId)
        .SelectMany(p => p.PromotionTopicJoins)
        .Select(pc => pc.Promotion)
        .Select(p => new PromotionDTO
        {
            PromotionId = p.PromotionId,
            // I've removed all the other fields
            Topics = p.PromotionTopicJoins.Select(itj => itj.PromotionTopic.Name).ToList()

        })
        .Where(x => x.Is_Active)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
        .ToListAsync();
```

The stacktrace is quite large, so I've only included the error and the preceding line.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The property '' on entity type
>   'PromotionTopicJoin' could not be found. Ensure that the property
>   exists and has been included in the model.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.MemberAccessBindingExpressionVisitor.GetPropertyPath(Expression
>   expression, QueryCompilationContext queryCompilationContext, out
>   QuerySourceReferenceExpression querySourceReferenceExpression)

FYI, my versions of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` went from 2.0.1 to 2.1.0

Comment: When you add a new migration, does it include something?

Comment: Which property? Please mention the property here

Comment: So you get exactly that message, with an empty string?

Comment: @Gert Confirming, the message is exact (with empty string) :(

Comment: @alsami No, nothing

Comment: @viveknuna That's the exact message, I don't know which property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a clear indication of EF Core query translation regression bug.

As such, all you can do is to report it to [EF Core Issue Tracker](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues). Provide the same minimal repro (remove the `.Where(x => x.Is_Active)` and `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)` - they don't compile currently, but the issue reproduces w/o them. Also reproduces with `ToList`, so it's not async related).

As a workaround until the issue is fixed, start the query directly from the join entity (the problem seems to be related to `SelectMany` navigation):

```
return await _context.Set<PromotionTopicJoin>()
    .Where(pc => pc.PromotionTopicId == TopicId)
    .Select(pc => pc.Promotion)
    .Select(p => new PromotionDTO
    {
        PromotionId = p.PromotionId,
        // I've removed all the other fields
        Topics = p.PromotionTopicJoins.Select(itj => itj.PromotionTopic.Name).ToList()    
    })
    .Where(x => x.Is_Active)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
    .ToListAsync();
```